# Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource when trying to add aggregation for two tables with ~500 work items in each

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi-desktop

I am using PowerBI and Azure DevOps. I have two tables User Story table (that holds all user stories) and Task table (that holds all tasks).

I have added filters so each table has around 500 work items in them.

I am merging the tables, that works fine. But then I want to expand the task table, and I want to add aggregation i.e. to summarize the values for some fields (Original Estimates, Completed Hours etc...)

After 30+ min ow working I am getting error

```
OLE DB or ODBC error: [Error] Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'AnalyticsBlockingResource' in namespace 'User'. 
For more information on why your request was blocked, see the topic "Rate limit=SUMX(FILTER(InternetSales, InternetSales[SalesTerritoryID]=5),[Freight])  
s" on the Microsoft Web site (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950)..
```

But this is strange, I only have 500 items in the tables. 
I feel this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. 
Instead of using the aggregation logic by editing and merging queries I am adding a new field into the User Story table and simply I am summarizing all work on the tasks by using the following statement.

```
SumOfOrgEstTask = CALCULATE(SUM(Task[Original Estimate]))
```

Works perfectly!